# swift function to show the score in the Game Center

Tags: swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I am developing a game with five scenes (SKSecne) in swift. I am using the following function to show the score in the Game Center at the end of each scene. Currently I have to copy the function to all the scene files.
How can I modify the function so I can call it from all the scene files without duplicating it?

```
func showLeader() {
    let viewControler = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    let gameCenter = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gameCenter.gameCenterDelegate = self
    viewControler?.presentViewController(gameCenter, animated: true, completion: nil) }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is just create a subclass of `SKScene` and use it like parent for others five scenes.

```
class BasicScene: SKScene {
   func showLeader() {}
}

class Scene1: BasicScene {
   // call showLeader() when needed 
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked! I had problem with functions that work with `self` . I wasn’t able to call them from different scenes. Now I can use subclass to fix this issue.